# Cross compile: linking to mysql, liblog4cpp, etc

Tags: debian, cross-compiling

Im attempting to cross-compile a project for an ARM processor system. I can get through the building steps but am failing at the link.

The app in question links with `liblog4cpp` and `libmysql`. To get the build working I copied down the relevant files from an ARM system but it appears that there are run-time dependencies . Specific error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.4.5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld:  
  warning: libz.so.1, needed by /usr/lib/mysql_arm/libmysqlclient.so,   
  not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)   
/usr/lib/mysql_arm/libmysqlclient.so: undefined reference to `compress'
/usr/lib/mysql_arm/libmysqlclient.so: undefined reference to `uncompress'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

In my build step I'm linking to libz.so but the suggestion to use `-rpath` makes me wonder if the mysql libraries want a runtime link. If I set this value on my build system will it get upset when it can't find the corresponding path on the run system?

Alternatively - is there a way to use `apt-get` to install files for other targets? I have the cross-compiler installed from emdebian but I don't see a way to get the library files for specific targets without mangling the build system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity: If you want to include other libraries and run into this sort of error message:

use the `-rpath-link` to point to the folder(s) containing your additional run-time libraries. The caveat being that your build statement (in this case **arm-linux-gnueabi-g++**) has to preface commands like this with **-Wl,**. So the resulting command would look something like:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wall -O0 <other params here> file0.o file1.o 
  -Wl,-rpath-link /usr/lib/<path to arm library for run-time> 
  -L <some other library path> -l <something like mysql or bluetooth>
```

The important part being the 2nd line. This gets resolved properly on the build machine AND on the machine its run on.